# How to read large Base64 file (150MB) on android app?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read large `base64` Text File with size `(~ 150MB)` on android application.

The file contains JSON string that i need to decode and transform it to an JSON object, and use it along the app. The problem is that I'm getting an exception `Out of Memory` while trying to read this data.

The app needs to work offline so I need to download the full data.

Here's the code:

```
    String localPath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath().toString() ;
    String key = "dataFile.txt" ;

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    File file=new File(localPath+"/"+ key);

    byte fileContent[] = new byte[3000];

    try ( FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        while(fin.read(fileContent) >= 0) {
            byte[] data = Base64.decode(fileContent, Base64.DEFAULT);
            try {
                text.append(new String(data, "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        obj = new JSONObject(text.toString());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can i read this kind of file?

Comment: You start by firing whoever thought that base64-encoded JSON was a good idea, then revamp the server to hand you regular JSON. Your resulting ~110MB JSON string is still too large to parse using `JSONObject`. If you only need a small subset of the data, use a streaming JSON parser (Gson, Jackson, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to read the the whole file into the `text` object by reading the file, iterating it and appending each line to `text`. You create the `JSONObject` out of your `text` object which is actually useful for your application only in the last step.

Here, by the time your code reaches the line `obj = new JSONObject(text.toString());` you have already filled up the heap with nearly the size of your Input File as this complete file is in the memory in the form of the `test` object. You then make `JSONObject` of of this `text` object.

What you can do to eliminate this problem is as follows:

1. Use `BufferedReader` to read the file in chunks (Optional). Using `read()` may be a bit slow and it is nice to have a buffer.
2. Iterate the file and put the entries into the `text` object in batches of `1000` or `10000`.
3. Prepare `JSONObject` out of `text` and append it to `obj`.
4. Clear the `text` object before processing the next batch and then repeat the whole process.

By doing this you are reading only a small portion of file in the memory and also `text` object is acting as a buffer, consuming only a small amount of the memory.

Here is the sample code snippet:

```
int counter = 0;
String temp = null;
final int BATCH_SIZE = 1000;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)) {

    while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(temp);
        ++counter;

        /* Process In Batches */
        if(counter % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
            /* Prepare & Append JSON Objects */
            obj = prepareAppendJSON(text.toString(), obj);
            /* Clear text */
            text.setLength(0);
        }
    }

    /* Last Iteration */
    obj = prepareAppendJSON(text, obj);
    text = new StringBuilder();

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but what is prepareAppendJSON method?

Comment: It is a custom object that you'll have to write to prepare the `JSONObject` out of the String and then append it to the given `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 2):

The only option you have is to use `JSON streaming` and react on events you are interested in.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.*;

.....

JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory().createJsonParser( yourFileInputStream );
parser.configure( Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true );
parser.configure( Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true );
// add more features

for( JsonToken token = parser.nextToken(); null != token; token = parser.nextToken() ){
  switch( token ){
    case FIELD_NAME:
      doStuffWithName();
      break;

    case START_OBJECT:
      doObjectStart();
      break;

    case END_OBJECT:
      processObject();
      break;

    // other events
  }
}
```

I used the above code on 4.0 device and with JSON file of 10 MB.

PS. You gonna need to decode your original Base64 file first. Not sure if you can do it within a `java.io.Stream` on the fly. In the worst case unpack the Base64 file into a plain-json and then use JSON streaming code from above